# Why don't I have an Icons tab in my properties?

Tags: windows-11, icons

I'm trying to extract an icon from a .exe file, and there are 100 instructions around the web that tell you to go to the file properties and click on the "Icons" tab.  Except mine doesn't have that tab!  You can see from the properties that it indeed does have an icon, it's displayed right there.  How do I get to the missing tab?

Windows 11 if it makes a difference.

[image]

Comment: If you make a shortcut to the .exe, properties on the shortcut maybe have a 'Shortcut' tab with a 'Change icon ...' button in it

Comment: @JoakimElofsson yes, I did find that.  But the Change Icon dialog doesn't let you do anything other than select an icon, you can't export from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to **extract** an icon from a file in Windows, but that has nothing to do with the icons in a .lnk, or shortcut file.

To extract an icon one needs a third-party tool, such as [IconViewer](https://www.botproductions.com/iconview/download.html), [ResourcesExtract](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/resources_extract.html) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/resourcesextract/).

The *Change Icon...* **button** (not tab) allows one to set a different icon for a shortcut.

Comment: Yes, I know I can find a utility to do it.  My question is not about that.  I tried both the shortcut and the actual .exe file, the screen shot in the question is from the .exe.

Comment: AFAIK, *no* version of Windows has an "Icon" tab in the Properties of an executable. As stated, a third-party tool is needed to extract the icon.

Comment: You don't get to the missing tab because there isn't one.  I can tell by your question and your response to this answer that you need more understanding on how this all works.  The exe file contains resources that only a tool can extract.  Windows has no built in tool to access them.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I found some sites which suggested you needed to install IconViewer to add that page to your properties.  However I found this one that said it should be there just with Windows proper: https://www.thetechedvocate.org/how-to-extract-icons-from-application-exe-and-system-dll-files-in-windows-11-and-10/

Comment: Your link's "advice" has VERY incorrect information for #2 and #3.  Even the powershell stuff is wrong.  Why won't you take our advice and just download a tool as advised as #1 in your link or the rest of the people here?  Also, exe files can have MANY or ZERO icons.  Which one did you think you were going to get with a save?  We just want to help and I mean no offense but you simply don't seem to be listening to what experts here are telling you.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I am listening now.  It does appear I was under a misconception, and one of the references I was relying on was simply wrong.  I was trying to solve the problem without installing a utility of unknown provenance on my work PC.